# Changing SQL Alias Connection type in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We installed SharePoint 2013 using AutoSPInstaller and we found out that it created a SQL alias, but we were surprised to see the it did it using shared memory instead of TCP/IP as show below:

[image]

We would like to change it to TCP/IP, but if you try to change it we get an error message when we browse to CA:

```
> Server Error in '/' Application.
> 
> This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a
> server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from
> the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm,
> use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start
> menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.    Description: An
> unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
> request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
> error and where it originated in the code. 
> 
>  Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation
> can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by
> users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the
> configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use
> the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start
> menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.
> 
> Source Error: 
> 
> 
>  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
> 
> 
> Stack Trace: 
> 
> 
> 
> [InvalidOperationException: This operation can be performed only on a
> computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions
> in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this
> server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration
> Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010
> Products.]   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.AlternateServerUrlFromHttpRequestUrl(Uri
> url) +223   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext
> ctx) +432   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext
> context) +1070   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current() +114   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
> site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean
> bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken
> appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout,
> Boolean bAsAnonymous) +179   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode
> authenticationMode) +360   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny() +408   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32
> compatibilityLevel) +30   
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
> +99    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
> +66    Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
> app) +789   
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +610   
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +175   
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +423   
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +317
> 
> [HttpException (0x80004005): This operation can be performed only on a
> computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions
> in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this
> server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration
> Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010
> Products.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
> context) +565   
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +112    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +731
```

Any idea on how we change switch the protocol to TCP/IP without breaking SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step :

1. Disconnect the server from this sharepoint Farm using SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard
2. Change the conection type of alias
3. Reboot server
4. Launch SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard and reconnect the server using passphrase. Be careful if you want hosting Central Admin (click Advanced settings)

This works for me